# Can the event listeners pane in Chrome be refreshed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Using the chrome dev tools to see what listeners are on a node is giving me trouble. It seems it's not detecting listeners on my dynamically loaded content (though, unfortunately I haven't reproduced this in the fiddle). However, it doesn't register events being delegated by jQuery.

Is there any way I can "refresh" its "knowledge of events"?

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],
    p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0],
    vanillaListen = function () {
        console.log("clicked via just JS");
    };
//attach pure JS listener
//shows up in Event Listeners pane
p.addEventListener("click", vanillaListen);

//attach jquery listener
$("body").on("mouseover", "div", function () {
    console.log("div mouse'd over via jQuery"); //does not show up in Event Listeners pane
});

//attach listener from ajax loaded content
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/echo/html/",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {
                html: "<p onClick=\"alert('ajax attached inline event')\">dynamic &lt;p&gt;</p>",
                delay: 1
            },
            success: function (returnedData) {
                //inline onClick shows up in Event Listeners pane
                $("body").append(returnedData);
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yEXfx/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("body").on("mouseover", "div",
```

It does list the event, check out `body`.

The way you add the event listener is to add it to body and only trigger your listener when the source elment is div.

As you see in the image below when setting "selected nodes only"

[image]

using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>test</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
</head> 
 <body> 
    <div>add event listener to body but trigger only when it came from a div</div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
$("body").append("<p onClick=\"alert('ajax attached inline event')\">dynamic</p>");
$("body").on("customEvent", "div", function () {
    console.log("div mouse'd over via jQuery"); //does not show up in Event Listeners pane
});
     </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When adding content using jQuery append I did see the event listed. I am using Version 27.0.1453.116 m on Windows 7